# c++ 2D char array sometimes duplicates data in random position

Tags: c++, arrays, char, 2d

I am using a 2D char array to display a board on screen. Empty board is fulled with '.' (dots), the program write in a certain position an other char ('G'). The problem is that sometimes (more o less once every four times) a duplicate character appears in an other position.

```
 4 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 3 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 2 |G  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 |.  .  .  .  G  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f
```

Relevant code fragments are:

```
class Field
{
 public:
static const int FIELDWIDTH=6;
static const int FIELDHEIGHT=4;

char field[FIELDWIDTH][FIELDHEIGHT];
..
};

void Field::empty(void){
  for(int r=0; r<FIELDHEIGHT; r++)
    for(int c=0; c<FIELDWIDTH; c++)
      field[r][c] = '.';
};

Field::plot(){                   //Plots the board
for(int r=FIELDHEIGHT;r>0;r--){
    cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(' ') << r << " |";
    for(int c=0;c<FIELDWIDTH;c++)
      cout << field[r-1][c] << "  ";
    cout << "|" << endl;
  };
...
};

void Field::putChar(void){
...
(random definition of pr2 and pc2 and validation within limits)
...
 field[pr2][pc2]='G';
 printCors(pr2,pc2); //cout coordinate for debug
...
};
```

The only two assignations to field[][] are ONE in empty() and ONE in putChar(). empty() works as expected always resulting in a plot() so:

```
 4 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 3 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 2 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f
```

And the assignation in putChar is watched with the cout, which only output just one coordinate, nevertheless SOMETIMES one additional character appears with some relation with the expected one, here some runs:

```
b1=
 4 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 3 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 2 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 |.  G  .  .  .  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f

e2=
 4 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 3 |G  .  .  .  .  .  |
 2 |.  .  .  .  G  .  |
 1 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f

e4=
 4 |.  .  .  .  G  .  |
 3 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 2 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f

a1=
 4 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 3 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 2 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 |G  .  .  .  .  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f

a4=
 4 |G  .  .  .  .  .  |
 3 |.  .  .  .  G  .  |
 2 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f
```

If I comment the assignation to field[][]= in putChar() function the board is always empty as expected, if I add other assignation, sometimes both chars are repeats, sometimes one and sometimes anyone.

Testing with a fixed assignation in putChar():

```
void Field::putChar(void){
...
(random definition of pr2 and pc2 and validation within limits)
...
 field[2][5]='H';
...
};
```

results are always:

```
 4 |.  H  .  .  .  .  |
 3 |.  .  .  .  .  H  |
 2 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 |.  .  .  .  .  .  |
------------------------
    a  b  c  d  e  f
```

it appears that duplicate data follows a pattern, duplication appears always -4,1 when possible... but why?
If array limits change, this pattern change with pattern position -FIELDHEIGHT,1 relative to the good one.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to decide which dimension is X and which is Y.

Comment: field[2][5]='H'... Seems like it's a problem with OOB. Might want to check that pr never goes above FIELDWIDTH-1 and pc above FIELDHEIGHT-1 before anything else

Comment: [mcve], please.  (As it is, we can't run your code, so it's way harder to find the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

In `field[r-1][c]` r goes from `1` to `FIELDHEIGHT`, but the first dimension of `field` has `FIELDWIDTH` elements. I think you meant `field[c][r-1]` here.

Comment: Thanks. This was the main issue. I reviewed this order in all the assignations and it worked as expected. Excuse me for the stupid question, I could not see that before, nevertheless it is clear.